# The best way to install ruby on rails on linux for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, nginx, development-environment

I would like to install Linux for development of Ruby on Rails apps. I would like to know your recommendations for this.
E.g.:

1. Which distribution of Linux?
2. What is good to have for development? (Nginx, php as a service, ...?)
3. What about requirements for machine?

I would like to install it properly for the best confort in developing. I'm now developing on windows, and it is horrible... (e.g. too slow, ...)

I am not decided to develop on Windows 7 with Virtual machine or Linux (with less equipment). What about you? What do you like and what you could recommend and whot you couldn't? Is there really any advantage to developing on Unix systems?

I am quite novice, I tried to install Linux for developing, but I did not recognize any difference.

Do you have any recommendations how to develop properly?

I'm using on Windows 7: Sublime2, SmartGit, RailsInstaller, ConEmu and Xampp as a mysql server.

//please make the point bold, what are you answered

Comment: Voting to close: This is not going to garner answers that are based on fact, only opinion. There are multiple distributions of Linux that work well, the server environment has too many options, and the requirements of the machine are wide open as we have no idea what real requirements you have.

Answer (score 3):

I think the **Virtual Machine** is the best solution because it is pretty light, can be easily exported/copied (saved in Dropbox also!) and can be destroyed easily too.

---

This is my setup on my personal computer that I use sometimes when I work from home :

- **OS**: Windows 7 with Oracle's Virtual Box to manage a virtual machine
- 1 **Virtual Machine** with `Ubuntu 12.04` (I hate the desktop on the new ones and I use gnome-fallback-session)
- `Yakuake` as **terminal manager** (very handy: use ctrl+F12 anytime to open a dropdown window containing terminals)
- `RubyMine` as **editor** to code my stuff
- `Thin` as the **web server** (I think this is the default one included in Rails, no need for extra install)
- `git-gui` to manage my **stuff with Git**
- `rvm` as **Ruby Version Manager** (means you can work on projects using different ruby versions for each project)

My computer is a Asus UX32VD (Notebook), 6 Go RAM, CPU is a small i7. I gave 3 Go of RAM to my Virtual Machine, 1 processor core, and **it works great**! Very smooth, unless you open tons of tabs and watch several 1080p videos at the same time.

---

**Some links:**

- Yakuake http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/guake-yakuake.html
- RVM http://rvm.io/
- Rubymine http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/
- Git-gui https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Ubuntu 14.04 works fine. I recommend to use [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) versions. I use VM but as form me it's better for performance to use Ubuntu on your local machine. System requirements for OS you can find [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME).
2. The rails server command launches a small web server named WEBrick which comes bundled with Ruby. It's enought for development for me. Just use **rails s** command.
3. I use RubyMine and it's brilliant IDE. Strongly recommended for Ruby.
4. Also I recommend to install Ruby via rvm. It's very simple.

**Run terminal and use following commands:**

*Install dependencies for Ruby:*

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties -y
```

*Install Ruby*

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev -y
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc

rvm install 2.1.2

rvm use 2.1.2 --default
```

*Speed up your gem installations and have less clutter in your system, remove the rdoc and ri when installing new gems*

```
echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
```

*Install Rails*

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for you is `Ubuntu` where you can use the same console as many other linux guys. If you are persistant you could try Gentoo, Archlinux. Also if you want feel powerefull you could use Tiling WM also VIM, GIT and other console tools

As for ruby you could use `chruby + ruby-install` https://github.com/postmodern/chruby

Answer (score 1):

Tool such as Vagrant - https://www.vagrantup.com/ - are great because they allow a host (even Windows) to run any number of Linux systems as virtual machines. It's simple to install, great documentation and loads of example configuration - even pre-built Vagrant config for Rails: http://rove.io/?pattern=rails

You install Vagrant on your host machine and then can install any number of different Linux systems as virtual machines, these run your application in isolation and can be configured with any database (Postgres, MySQL,etc). You would edit the code on your host machine using your preferred editor and access the development app using port forwarding in your preferred browser. It's a great tool.

Personally, I use a Mac and OSX with Vagrant :)

Answer (score 1):

After some variants I prefer this:

```
ubuntu/debian - rbenv - bundler - rails (and other gems)
```

Here is per-user (preferable) installation manual:

[Setup Ruby On Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr - GoRails](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)